# Jquery toggle ul multi levels

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle

How can I toggle multi level's of a navigation.

I try with find ul of this, but then it open every submenu level.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="level_1">
<li class="submenu">sumenu
<ul class="level_2">
    <li class="submenu">level2
        <ul class="level_3">
        <li>level3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.submenu ul {
    display:none;
}
```

And here is my Jquery code

```
$( ".submenu" ).hover(function() {
  $( this).find("ul").toggle( "slow" );
});
```

So what I want is when I hover level_1 it should only open level_2 and when I hover then level_2 it should open level_3.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4cjQ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) as it get the immediate children. instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which gets descendants(child of child also)

*code*

```
$(".submenu").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("ul").toggle("slow");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4Vy8/)

Comment: Also probably best to split this out into `mouseover` and `mouseout` and use `show` and `hide` respectively.  That'll give you another edit Satpal :P

Comment: So and if i want to use click function for this how can i handle to leave level_1 open when i click on level_2? http://jsfiddle.net/E4Vy8/1/

Comment: Oky found solution 
$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});

Answer (score 0):

try this , hope it helps :

```
$( ".submenu" ).hover(function() {
  $( this).children("ul").first().toggle( "slow" );
});
```